# Google SERP showing indian rupees instead of Pakistan rupees even i have set up everything correctly

Tags: google

I am having this problem from a long time on my [website](https://phonehungers.com/) even i have tried everything that i can do. Whenever we open the site it shows pakistani rupees amount listed on products but in the google serp analysis it shows indian rupees that might be bad seo factor. If any one have solution to this problem please guide me.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Sorry, this question is about Google product, not related to Android, thus it's off-topic.